# How do I convert Excel char variables to numeric values after importing from Excel in R

Tags: excel, char, numeric, readxl

I know similar questions have been asked in the past but I am not able to find any that can solve my particular issue.

I have a data set which I have imported from Excel using both the read_excel function as well as trying to select file > import dataset > from excel. When I import the data it shows the columns with values in as 'doubles' but when I then view the data type using str(), once imported, it shows these as being a char variable. I have used many different functions to try convert from char to integer but I keep getting the 'NAs introduced by coercion' warning and the command does not seem to work.

The function I see come up mostly is as.numeric(as.character()) but this does not work.

The most common problem I see people having is that their data has "," however my data seems to be formatted correctly using ".".

This is causing me issues as I am then not able to filter out values outside of a certain range.

Would anyone have any ideas on what I could be doing wrong as I have literally spent hours trying to solve for this issue and am now completely stuck but sure it is a simple fix.

Comment: Is fixing the data in Excel and then re-import an option?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. I have amended the data in Excel as I think the file was corrupted some how. Thanks again.